# How I Create a GridView Inside a Fragment in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, gridview, android-studio

I'm new in Android but know the most basics.I want to create a custom `GridView` like one shown `spotify` browse page but inside a `Fragment Tab`. I have searched online but found nothing just gridview tutorials on activity page. But I would like to implement mine on a `fragment Tab`.

It will be cool if I could have each grid item opening a new page using some sort of click listener.

so far, I already created

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<GridView
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/form_grid"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

The tab xml supporting the gridview.

and here below is the grid_row.xml layout itself

```js
< FrameLayout xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: orientation = "vertical" >

  < ImageView
android: id = "@+id/grid_image"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_gravity = "top" / >

  < TextView
android: id = "@+id/grid_label"
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "45dp"
android: layout_marginTop = "175dp"
android: background = "@drawable/ic_header_logo"
android: gravity = "center"
android: textColor = "#FFFFFF"
android: textSize = "12sp"
android: textStyle = "bold" / >
  < /FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had issues about using more than one 'Layout' with Android Studio, in this case, also the fragment counts as layout, and I would recommend you to write the layouts manually and then switch to the graphical interface.

**EDIT** use a linearlayout and a gridview inside.... see comments

Comment: I just re-edited the question.Im not sure about the answer by 'view' in my case my tab.xml fragment contains the gridview.But Im sure I will need something like a base adapter .Anywhere I dont use graphical interface much

Comment: Me too.... mistake. do you only use the gridview inside the linearlayout? if so, why not deleting the linearlayout and change the gridview to a gridlayout

Comment: Woah. I get it So more like I should cancel the LinearLayout parent and just begin the xml with gridview it self

Comment: Sorry but I m new .Its kinda confusing when you say GridLayout above Gridview since the fragment itself is a view.?